# Write data from kmz on sheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, kmz

I'm very new in Google Apps Script. I have to read data from multiple kmz (placemarks and desccriptions mainly). So far I have managed to read and parse it with XmlService. What is the best way to transfer data to the spreadsheet?

```
  var kmzFile = DriveApp.getFileById('<ID>').getBlob();
  var unzipBlobs = Utilities.unzip (kmzFile.setContentType('application/zip'));
  var xml = unzipBlobs[0].getDataAsString()
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml)
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var nameSpace = root.getNamespace()
  var folderRoot = root.getChild('Document', nameSpace).getChild('Folder', nameSpace)
  var folders = folderRoot.getChildren('Folder', nameSpace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to parse the kmz depends on the structure of the specific document, but assuming your data of interest is contained in `folders`:

Here is a sample of how to insert the retrieved kmz data into a new sheet of a given spreadsheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PASTE THE SPREADSHEET ID HERE");
var newSheet = ss.insertSheet();
var values = [];
if(folders.length!=0){
  for (var i = 0; i< folders.length; i++){
      values[i]=[];
      values[i].push(folders[i]);
    }
  newSheet.getRange(1,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
```

Basically, you iterate through all `folders` and dynamically create a value range of the size of the data and then assign it to a range in a sheet.